# Translating "comments", "leave a comment", "prev", "next", "share"

Tags: translation

I have a problem to locate ""comments", "Leave a comment", and similar words within post section of the WP theme. I need to translate those words to another language, but they are not visible in PO/POT files. Could soumeone suggest the solution.

Comment: Did you locate them in the code? Can you say if they are wrapped within an internationalization function, like `__('comments')`?

Comment: Let me check and I will reply

Answer (score 0):

1. you can Look at `wp-includes/comment-template.php` for available solutions
2. Try to install this plugin [WP Native Dashboard](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-dashboard/), load your needed language files 
   hopes its help you .....

Comment: Thanks for your reply